# i can not run my app because SDK 26 > device SDK 24?

Tags: android

When I want to run app on my phone I face this proplem: min sdk 26 > device sdk24
How can I fix that?

build gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asus.order"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Add Library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: If your _device_ has lower SDK that your app requires, then you can only "fix" that by lowering your app requirements to earlier SDK version.

Comment: "instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk"  what i do?

Comment: it still same problem and my app open and close in same time :( .. why? please help

Comment: is it mean there is problems some where in code ?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `minSdkVersion` to 24 or lower

Comment: if i change minsdkversion to 24, there is another problem: Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.example.asus.order signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Comment: i press ok and after build and run, show this: nstant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk

Comment: try invalided caches. Hope the problem will be solved.